# Нестандартное оформление прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Дан текст:

"Все гости начали громко жаловаться на погоду. Неужели и в Англии так же холодно, хотели знать они. Только летом, сострил я, и на мгновение они, кажется, поверили и пришли в ужас..."

К какому виду сложных предложений относятся предложения 2 и 3?

Предложение 2 похоже на сложноподчиненное с изъяснительной частью, но подчинительного союза там нет; кроме того, в "главной части" изменен порядок слов, а зачем?

Предложение 3 содержит явную прямую речь, но она не оформлена по правилам.

Почему автор применяет такое построение текста, что это ему дает? И в каких случаях можно не придерживаться строгих правил?

Comment: Год в Провансе. Автор:Питер Мейл (https://www.litres.ru/piter-meyl/god-v-provanse-6601039/chitat-onlayn/). © И. Пандер (наследники), перевод, 2014

Answer (score 1):

Как указано в комментарии, это цитата из перевода книги "Год в Провансе" Питера Мейла. На английском этот фрагмент выглядит следующим образом:

> ...and we were caught in a crossfire of noisy complaints about the weather. Was it as bad as this in England? Only in the summer, I said. For a moment they took me seriously before someone saved me from embarrassment by laughing.

Перевод довольно вольный, в нём изменена структура предложений и некоторые краски. Но и в английском варианте прямая речь не выделена по всем законам пунктуации.

[Часто разделяют reported and direct speech](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/punctuation-in-direct-speech), и, скорее всего, автор старается подчеркнуть именно тот факт, что "Only in the summer" не обязательно было сказано героем конкретно этими словами и передает лишь близкий смысл. Хотя скорее автор в оригинале [все же "нарушает"](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/articles/zhqh92p).

Теперь вопрос, насколько переводчик постарался сохранить авторскую задумку? Судя по этому отрывку и конкретно этому критерию — на 5+. В оригинальном тексте полно и правильно оформленной прямой речи. Например (через пару страниц после обсуждаемого фрагмента),

> "Bonjour." He unscrewed a cigarette butt from the corner of his mouth and introduced himself. "Massot, Antoine."

переведено диалогом.

> — Bon jour. — Человек выплюнул прилепившийся в уголке рта окурок и представился: — Массо, Антуан.

То есть переводчик сохранил (как минимум в этих отрывках) изначальную задумку автора по оформлению.

Я бы классифицировал такое пунктуационное оформление как авторские знаки. В художественной литературе придерживаться строгих правил, конечно же, необязательно. И чем она художественней, и чем вы более известный автор – тем более их можно не придерживаться. Была бы хорошая причина это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Это так называемая несобственно-прямая речь. Здесь, правда, её распознавание несколько осложнено тем, что в обоих случаях нет союза (союзного слова), её вводящего, но это ведь и не обязательно.

http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/nesobstvenno-pryamaya-rech/?q=486&n=1075

Что касается типа предложения (2), то его и не надо здесь рассматривать как сложное. 
Это простое предложение, осложненное несобственно-прямой речью.

А вот (3) скорее всего надо признать сложносочиненным. Хотя тут есть варианты.

В общем, думаю, такой вольный - с точки зрения грамматики - текст и не стоит загонять в прокрустово ложе систематики синтаксиса.