# Помогите разобраться с пунктуацией в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, кавычки, сложное-предложение

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

> И какой бинокль!, восклицаешь ты, «легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь.

Comment: Для правильного оформления прямой речи желательно видеть контекст.  В некоторых случаях дословное высказывание может встраиваться в текст,  а слова автора обособляются как вводное предложение.

Comment: Да, мне бы не хотелось использовать прямую речь. Это перевод текста, главный герой ставит в кавычки (цитирует) лишь слово "легендарный". Подскажите, как бы выглядело предложение в таком случае? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зачем кавычить *легендарный*? Перебор с кавычками будет, для художественного-то текста.

Comment: Согласна с вами, просто поясняю, как у автора.

Comment: Почему Фуджинон в кавычках? Гугл дает без кавычек, хотя и предпочитает латинское Fujinon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*«И какой бинокль! — восклицаешь ты, — легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь».*

Или:

*— И какой бинокль, — восклицаешь ты, — легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь!*

Или (что лучше):

**— И какой бинокль! — восклицаешь ты. — Легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь!**

---

См. [§ 49.4-5](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html) - не хотят оне моих первых двух варьянтов, но, полагаю, допустимо.

---

Кстати о птицах: **[Ю́дзи Хякута́кэ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%8D,_%D0%AE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B8)**.

Comment: Спасибо (особенно за поправку в имени). Подскажите, а можно обойтись без прямой речи или это будет некорректно?

Comment: Думаю, что можно обойтись, но это будет другая, особая интонация - без восклицания (хотя текст прямо на это указывает). У нас ведь пересказ чужого восклицания, а рассказчик может просто констатировать, повествовательно. Тогда будет так: ***И какой бинокль, восклицаешь ты, легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь.***

Comment: Спасибо! Мне кажется, этот вариант больше подходит.

Comment: Юля! Здесь "спасибо" изображается так: клик по верхнему треугольничку и по нижней галочке! )))

Answer (score 2):

Если прямая речь состоит из **нескольких предложений** и слова автора стоят между ними, то после первой части прямой речи ставится **восклицательный знак** (в нашем случае) **и тире**; слова автора пишутся со строчной буквы, после них ставятся **точка и тире**; вторая часть прямой речи начинается **с прописной буквы**. Кавычки ставятся только в начале и в конце прямой речи.
**«П! — а. — П».** или **— П! — а. — П.**

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://lingvotech.com/znaki_prepinaniya_pri_pryamoy_rechi)

«И какой бинокль! — восклицаешь ты. — Легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь».
Или без кавычек, но с начальным тире.

Пример [Грамоты](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr):
– Ну, полно, полно! – сказал Печорин, обняв его дружески. – Неужели я не тот же? (Лермонтов)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Answer (score 0):

Оформление прямой речи, **встроенной в текст** (слова автора являются вводным предложением):

И какой бинокль! ―   восклицаешь ты. Легендарный «Фуджинон», с помощью которого Юджи Хиякутаке увидел свою комету, позже названную в его честь.

Пример:

Давайте, спасибо, **говоришь ты, улыбаясь,** хотя от твоей улыбки нет никакого проку.. [Саша Соколов. Школа для дураков (1976)]

Comment: Где описан такой прием? И не является ли это ответом и на Ваш вопрос об оформлении прямой речи:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444969/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8

Comment: Однако здесь второе предложение — это слова героя, а не автора.  А в Вашем варианте как это понять?

Comment: В обоих случаях автор текста ведет рассказ, вспоминает о чем-то: что у него спросили, что он ответил, или просто вспоминает ситуацию, в том числе чьи-то слова. У него нет желания обозначать прямую речь, выделять диалоги,  ему нужен компактный текст воспоминаний, изображенный как потока сознания. Другой вариант: иногда он, как художник на картине,  переходит от второго плана воспоминаний к первому плану, то есть подробному изображению какой-либо сценки с диалогами. Всё это можно видеть в книгах, но не в правилах.

Comment: В своем же вопросе мне  хотелось узнать про такие правила (существуют они или нет), а также понять суть художественного приема в конкретном случае.

Comment: И еще. Если автор избрал некий "облегченный" вариант изложения, то почему Фуджинон в кавычках? Гугл дает без кавычек, хотя и предпочитает латинское Fujinon.

Comment: Облегченный вариант в плане построения текста,  но к названию техники это не относится, там свои правила. Фуджинон  пишут по-разному: с прописной буквы, со строчной буквы, в кавычках и без них, на форуме его даже фуджиком могут назвать. Я думаю, что здесь на запись  могло повлиять наличие определения: "Легендарный Фуджинон" можно прочитать как имя собственное.

Comment: Нашла на Грамоте: названия производственных марок технических изделий (автомобилей, самолетов, приборов и др.): автомобили «Волга», «Тойота», самолеты «Руслан», «Боинг-747», стиральная машина «Индезит», газовая плита «Ардо». Написанные латиницей названия не заключаются в кавычки, например: персональные компьютеры Kraftway Idea, Apple iMac.

Comment: @Юлия, Та же Грамота пишет, что прямая речь заключается в кавычки. Если автор выбрал "облегченный" вариант изложения (не сторого по правилам), то и Фуджинон можно писать без кавычек. Но это на совести автора.